# Recursive call inside jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

Why is the function working only once in the below code ?

```
(function ( $ ) {

$.fn.test = function() {

   setInterval(hi.call(this), 1000);

   function hi(){
    console.log(this);
   }
};

}( jQuery ));


$('div').test();
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it, it's only called once ?

Comment: @adeneo I am trying to call it recursively using `setInterval`

Comment: You are calling it, then passing the return value (`undefined`) of the function to `setInterval` because you use `call` and the function returns nothing. there's absolutely no recursion going on here.

Comment: You're passing `undefined` to that interval ?

Comment: `setInterval(hi.bind(this), 1000);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`call()` calls the function with a this-value and optional arguments, it would be the same as

```
setInterval(hi(), 1000);
```

and as that function doesn't return anything, it's the same as

```
var x = hi(); // undefined

setInterval(x, 1000);
       //   ^ still undefined
```

What you wanted was to create a new function with a given this-value using `bind()`

```
setInterval(hi.bind(this), 1000);
```

A little more jQuery'ish using [`$.proxy`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

```
setInterval( $.proxy(hi, this), 1000);
```